# Understanding the performance of Haskell functions

Tags: performance, haskell, recursion, higher-order-functions

I was writing a haskell program where I needed to zip two lists with a function, but I didn't want it to stop at the end of the shorter list (like the standard version of `zipWith`) but rather continue until the end of the longer list, using some default value after reaching the end of the shorter list. My first implementation looked like this:

```
zipWithAll :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll f x y = go
    where go []     []     = []
          go (a:as) []     = f a y : go as []
          go []     (b:bs) = f x b : go [] bs
          go (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : go as bs
```

However, I usually prefer writing functions using the standard library higher order functions, rather than using explicit recursion, since it often increases performance and makes the code nicer to look at. So I tried this:

```
zipWithAll' :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll' f x y xs ys = zipWith f xs' ys'
    where n   = max (length xs) (length ys)
          xs' = take n $ xs ++ repeat x
          ys' = take n $ ys ++ repeat y
```

To me this looked much worse performance wise, since using length twice means two more list traversals. But surprisingly, when I compared the average time, the first version was about 20% slower than the second.

So, I figured I would go with the second one and add arguments for the length of the lists, since in some cases, they would be known beforehand. Thus, I wrote this:

```
zipWithAll'' :: (a -> b -> c) -> Int -> Int -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll'' f n m x y xs ys = zipWith f xs' ys'
    where k   = max n m
          xs' = take k $ xs ++ repeat x
          ys' = take k $ ys ++ repeat y
```

But, even more surprisingly, the third version only improved performance by a tiny margin. For two randomly generated lists of `Int`, `xs` and `ys`, `length xs = length ys = n = 1000000`, I got the following:

```
| function                       | average time, 30 evaluations |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
| zipWithAll   (+) 0 0 xs ys     |                        1.20s |
| zipWithAll'  (+) 0 0 xs ys     |                        0.95s |
| zipWithAll'' (+) n n 0 0 xs ys |                        0.94s |
+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I get that this isn't the most comprehensive benchmarking test, but still, it seems to go against all my intuition for what makes haskell programs run faster. It makes me think that I'm missing something important for understanding the performance of haskell functions.

So basically what I would like to know is this:

Why is the simple recursive approach the slowest? Is it just due to optimizations done for the standard `zipWith` function? If so, is there something I could do to make it perform similarly to `zipWith`?

Also, am I wrong in assuming that the second version does `3n` operations while the third only does `n`? If so, why doesn't this have a greater impact on performance? I could imagine this being less relevant if the zipping function was very time consuming but I'm only using `(+)` here.

Finally, is there a way to implement a faster `zipWithAll`, by taking advantage of the optimizations for the standard library functions, without knowing the lengths of the lists beforehand?

(Edit)
This is the relevant parts of the benchmarking code that I used.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Monad (replicateM, forM_)
import Data.Foldable (foldl')
import Data.Time (diffUTCTime, getCurrentTime, NominalDiffTime)
import Numeric (showEFloat, showFFloat)
import Test.QuickCheck

main = do
    let n  = 1000000
        fs = [ ("zipWithAll", uncurry4 $ zipWithAll (+))
             , ("zipWithAll'", uncurry4 $ zipWithAll' (+))
             , ("zipWithAll''", uncurry4 $ zipWithAll'' (+) n n)]

    xs <- generate (vectorOf n arbitrary :: Gen [Int])
    ys <- generate (vectorOf n arbitrary :: Gen [Int])
    benchmark fs (0, 0, xs, ys) 30

uncurry4 :: (a -> b -> c -> d -> e) -> (a,b,c,d) -> e
uncurry4 f (a,b,c,d) = f a b c d

-- | Measure and print the average time it takes for each function in the list to return.
benchmark :: (Show a, Show b) => [(String, (a -> b))] -> a -> Int -> IO ()
benchmark fs x rep = do
    force x
    forM_ fs $ \(name, f) -> do
        ts <- replicateM rep (measureTime f x)
        putStrLn $ "function: " ++ name ++ ", time = " ++ (showSignificant 2 $ average ts)

-- | Get the time measurement for a function applied to an arguemnt
measureTime :: Show b => (a -> b) -> a -> IO NominalDiffTime
measureTime f x = do
    t1 <- getCurrentTime
    force (f x)
    t2 <- getCurrentTime
    return $ diffUTCTime t2 t1

-- | Force the computation of a value
force :: Show a => a -> IO ()
force a = maximum (show a) `seq` return ()


-- | Show a time difference using @n@ significant figures
showSignificant :: Int -> NominalDiffTime -> String
showSignificant n a = showFFloat Nothing b "s"
  where
    ae = showEFloat (Just (n-1)) (fromRational (toRational a)) ""
    b  = read ae :: Double

-- | Take the average of the elements in a foldable data structure
average :: (Foldable t, Fractional a) => t a -> a
average = uncurry (/) . foldl' f (0,0)
    where f (s,l) x = (s', l')
            where !s' = x + s
                  !l' = 1 + l
```

Comment: I think it's important to show the code you used to time your code. E.g. if you do (pseudocode) `let xs = random ; printTime ; foo xs ; printTime ; bar xs ; printTime` then you might be unfair to `foo` since its time will include the cost of lazily-generating the random `xs`, unlike for `bar`. For a quick test, try swapping the order of your benchmark and see if something changes.

Comment: You include the benchmarking results, but not your benchmarking methodology (i.e., code). In order to reproduce your results, any prospective answerers will need to waste time implementing their own benchmark. More importantly, benchmarking is notoriously tricky to do from scratch, and I wouldn't be at all surprised if your benchmark code doesn't measure what you think it does.

Comment: @amalloy I have added the relevant parts of the benchmarking code now (minus the parts that prints progress and shows the results in a table since it depends on another module). I didn't write the force function myself, but if it works as intended it should force the argument before applying it to the functions.

Comment: Could not reproduce. Here, no-primes is consistently fastest, followed by two-primes, followed by one-prime. That matches my intuition: the hand-coded loop is fastest, the one that assumes length information next, and the one that traverses the list twice is last. Just to double-check: are you compiling your benchmark with optimizations on? (And, for what it's worth, I find the hand-coded loop *more* idiomatic than the ones that try to force the use of library functions.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Foolish enough, I only ran the benchmark in ghci. Once I compiled it with all the optimizations on, it did produce the expected results. Can the difference be explained by the fact that when you run a module from ghci, the library functions are compiled and optimized while 'hand-coded' functions are not?

Comment: @user20726076 Indeed. Code from compiled libraries is loaded as compiled object code in ghci. Code from the current environment is interpreted. That's certainly a factor.

Comment: I must agree with Daniel, your first version is the "nicest" Haskell to me. Preferring library functions means don't reimplement special cases that are easily writeable as calls to library functions, it doesn't mean go so far as to introduce extra passes (or worse, synthetic arguments that the caller has to know a magical correct value for!) just for the sake of avoiding recursion. The `length` based one also no longer works for potentially-infinite lists, and will always both lists force into memory, even if you only use a small part of the output - it's less useful as well as less "nice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criterion is the gold standard for benchmarking in Haskell. I don't really believe benchmarks that come from anywhere else, so I ported your suite to Criterion. I've included my source file at the bottom of this Answer, so that in case I have done something wrong, someone can fix it easily. One important difference: I made the lists `xs` and `ys` different sizes, to actually exercise the interesting part of your function: `ys` is twice as big as `xs`. Here are the results I see:

```
benchmarking standalone/zipWithAll
time                 18.53 ms   (18.08 ms .. 18.96 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.993 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 19.77 ms   (19.28 ms .. 20.40 ms)
std dev              1.345 ms   (1.021 ms .. 1.711 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 30% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking standalone/zipWithAll'
time                 43.61 ms   (43.25 ms .. 44.00 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 43.37 ms   (43.27 ms .. 43.57 ms)
std dev              256.9 μs   (140.4 μs .. 437.6 μs)

benchmarking standalone/zipWithAll''
time                 27.65 ms   (27.32 ms .. 28.20 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.997 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 27.58 ms   (27.40 ms .. 27.92 ms)
std dev              513.2 μs   (339.7 μs .. 770.0 μs)
```

Your simple recursive approach is twice as fast as the version that traverses the list twice - not so surprising, really! If you pass the sizes up front, you save some of that extra expense, but you're still doing concatenation and `take`, neither of which is free, so you come out noticeably behind.

Why is the simple version fastest? You mention that `zipWith` has an optimized implementation in the standard library, but if you [look at it](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#zipWith), you'll see that its implementation is exactly what you or I would have written. The one interesting thing is the note about fusion, which I think mostly means that, if you write `map succ (zipWith f (filter even xs) ys)` or something of the like, it can fuse the `filter`, `zipWith` and `map` into a single looping operation, without having to materialize intermediate lists. So, I lied when above I claimed my only interesting modification to your suite was to change the list sizes. I also added benchmarks for using the functions in this way, which we can see here:

```
benchmarking fused/zipWithAll
time                 43.80 ms   (43.43 ms .. 44.29 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 43.65 ms   (43.41 ms .. 43.94 ms)
std dev              522.9 μs   (374.5 μs .. 651.1 μs)

benchmarking fused/zipWithAll'
time                 132.3 ms   (128.3 ms .. 138.7 ms)
                     0.998 R²   (0.994 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 131.4 ms   (127.6 ms .. 133.7 ms)
std dev              4.495 ms   (2.430 ms .. 6.794 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 11% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking fused/zipWithAll''
time                 52.83 ms   (52.36 ms .. 53.36 ms)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 52.51 ms   (52.34 ms .. 52.72 ms)
std dev              366.1 μs   (246.8 μs .. 486.0 μs)
```

Version 1 is still the winner, but version 2 has gotten even worse while version 3 has narrowed the gap. Is this evidence of anything in particular? Maybe it suggests that some of the excess operations do get fused when using `zipWithAll''`. Probably not, though - I bet the `f` and `f'` lambdas make it too hard for GHC to inline all the way. But I'd have to look at the core to get any better guesses, and I don't have time to get into that right now. You can give it a try with `-ddump-simpl` if you want.

---

As promised, here's the code for my benchmark:

```
module Main (main) where

import Criterion.Main
import Test.QuickCheck

zipWithAll :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll f x y = go
    where go []     []     = []
          go (a:as) []     = f a y : go as []
          go []     (b:bs) = f x b : go [] bs
          go (a:as) (b:bs) = f a b : go as bs

zipWithAll' :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll' f x y xs ys = zipWith f xs' ys'
    where n   = max (length xs) (length ys)
          xs' = take n $ xs ++ repeat x
          ys' = take n $ ys ++ repeat y

zipWithAll'' :: (a -> b -> c) -> Int -> Int -> a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWithAll'' f n m x y xs ys = zipWith f xs' ys'
    where k   = max n m
          xs' = take k $ xs ++ repeat x
          ys' = take k $ ys ++ repeat y

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let xSize = 1000000
      ySize = xSize * 2
  xs <- generate (vectorOf xSize arbitrary :: Gen [Int])
  ys <- generate (vectorOf ySize arbitrary :: Gen [Int])
  let impls = [ ("zipWithAll", zipWithAll (+) 0 0)
              , ("zipWithAll'", zipWithAll' (+) 0 0)
              , ("zipWithAll''", zipWithAll'' (+) xSize ySize 0 0)
              ]
  defaultMain [ bgroup "standalone" $ do
                  (name, f) <- impls
                  let f' (xs, ys) = f xs ys
                  pure . bench name $ nf f' (xs, ys)
              , bgroup "fused" $ do
                  (name, f) <- impls
                  let f' (xs, ys) = map succ (f (filter even xs) ys)
                  pure . bench name $ nf f' (xs, ys)
              ]
```

Comment: Note that the "fused" benchmarks are set up to provide fusion opportunities, but no fusion is actually done.  You need `zipWithAll`-specific `RULES` pragmas to actually fuse.  In particular, if you make the two lists the same size and add plain `zipWith` for comparison, it's about the same speed as `zipWithAll` for the "standalone" benchmarks but 50% faster than `zipWithAll` for the "fused" benchmarks.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Interesting. When I make the change you suggest, I see that `zipWith` performs the same as `zipWithAll` in both standalone and fused groups. Specifically, I added ` ("zipWith", zipWith (+)` as a test case, and defined `ySize = xSize`. Am I missing some change that you made to get those numbers?

Comment: No, those were the only changes I made.  I have 11ms for `standalone/zipWithAll` versus 9-10ms for `standalone/zipWith`, and 28ms for `fused/zipWithAll` versus 19ms for `fused/zipWith`.  I'm testing with GHC 9.2.4 and `-O2`.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I'm on 9.2.5. I had been using `stack run` to build, with the belief that it passes `-O2` for me. I've since confirmed that it behaves the same when I `stack ghc -- -O2 src/Main.hs; ./src/Main`. I see `zipWith` very close in speed to `zipWithAll` in standalone, and about 10% faster in fused.